# How to use different parameter values in an RSpec mock/stub?

Tags: rspec, mocking, zip, rspec-rails, stubbing

My program downloads a zip file from the web then parses it. The relevant parsing-related code is:

```
Zip::File.open("real_file.zip") do |zip_file|
  # do stuff
end
```

In my RSpec test environment, I'd like to stub this code to parse a fake/mock file instead of the real one. Specifically, I'd like to replace the parameter value "real_file.zip" with "mock_file.zip".

I tried the following approach:

```
allow(Zip::File).to receive(:open).and_return(Zip::File.open("mock_file.zip"))
```

... but this prevents execution of code inside the block (`# do stuff`). I don't want the mock file contents to be *returned* by the method, but rahter to be assigned to the value of `zip_file` for further use. How can this be achieved?

Comment: I think you want `allow(Zip::File).to receive(:open) { |&block| block.call(Zip::File.open('mock_file.zip')) }`

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/configuring-responses/block-implementation#yield-to-the-caller's-block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you want to do:

```
mock_file = Zip::File.open('mock_file.zip')
allow(Zip::File).to receive(:open) { |&block| block.call(mock_file) }
```

What you're doing here is yielding a value to the block in your original code. The problem with simply returning a scalar value is that it doesn't yield anything to your block so it won't be called. *Note* that I'm opening the mock file before putting in the message expectation since it would also intercept your call to `Zip::File.open` and cause a nice stack overflow.

More information: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/configuring-responses/block-implementation#yield-to-the-caller's-block

Comment: success! i had come across this strategy earlier but couldn't figure out how to translate the documentation examples to fit my own application. thanks @mroach